# Anime TV show (2000s) in which the characters analyse the creature stats using a device similar to a Pokédex

Tags: story-identification, anime

There was this anime TV show in the 2000s, which featured the main character fighting against the evils on getting the 5 legendary creatures. Whoever can get all 5 of them together will unleash the mythical creature with the best stats (attack 10 defence 10 and etc).

They used a device somewhat like the Pokédex from *Pokémon* to identify the creature and showed their stats. The stats are read off in the order, "attack 10 defence 10..."

Comment: Been a while since I've watched *Digimon* episodes but the Digivice behaved a lot like a Pokédex. Maybe one of the numerous *Digimon* runs then?

Comment: Duel Masters? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PqvOWXBOEv0

Comment: Yu ki oh possibly?

Comment: Yo-Kai watch maybe?